# Redux proper location/method to store state value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently I am using an `action` to pass a data value, as so...

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.getSource("hello")}>Check</button>
```

I am passing `hello` to the following action...

```
export const getSource = (string) => {
    return {
        type: "SOURCE_RECEIVED",
        payload: string
    }
}
```

I also have an action listener in my app that listens for this action...

```
export default function (state=null, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "SOURCE_RECEIVED":
            return action.payload;
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

I am also combining the action listener...

```
import String from './reducer-listener';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    source: String
});
```

To create the store I am using the following code...

```
import allReducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(allReducers);

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Layout/>
    </Provider>
    , app);
```

My issue is, I want to save the string `hello` in the app's current state so that it can be retrieved or updated later. Right now all I am doing is taking the string and printing it out to the console. I do not know what the proper way to store a state's value using redux.

How can I update my code so that I can save the `hello` string in a location where it can be retrieved later?

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to setup the redux store, as well as what you're doing to use the value in the app (where you are thinking about retrieving it later)?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read the office redux docs first before going any further. http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/

Comment: @LancePollard ok I added the code to create the store. The example above with `onClick` is temporary, when the app loads I want the `string` to be saved somewhere, and I want it to be retrieved later when the user click on a button...I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs on `mapStateToProps` here:

- http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#container-components
- https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Essentially you want to "connect" your component to the redux store like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    source: state.source
  }
}

const TheConnectedComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(TheComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a reducer like below

```
 var userReducer = function (state = {}, action) {   
     switch (action.type) {
            case 'SET_NAME':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    name: action.name
                }
            default:
                return state;
      }
}
```

You can create the store using the below code

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
let store = createStore(userReducer)
```

at this moment you can test the state by

```
console.log('store state after initialization:', store.getState())
```

Create action creator like this

```
var setNameActionCreator = function (name) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_NAME',
        name: name
    }
}
```

You can store any value to the store by dispatching the action creator like below

```
store.dispatch(setNameActionCreator('bob'))
```

Dispatch function is provided by Redux and will propagate our action and it can be called in your button click

You will get the updated state by

```
console.log('store state after action SET_NAME:', store.getState())
```